# VBA shortest way to check cells on containing specific text

Tags: excel, vba

I have some VBA code working but would like to know if there is an easier way of coding this.  I have a list of 100 unique values and want to assign a category to each of the values and write the category name in another cell

I have working if-else statement that checks each value and outputs a category.

```vb
Sub AssignCategory()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A100")
For Each cell In rng.Cells
    If InStr(1, cell, "Apple") Then
        cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Fruit"
    ElseIf InStr(1, cell, "Racoon") Then
        cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Animal"
    ElseIf InStr(1, cell, "Lion") Then
        cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Animal"
    ElseIf InStr(1, cell, "Quartz") Then
        cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Mineral"
    ElseIf InStr(1, cell, "Watermelon") Then
        cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Fruit"
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

The code is working, but can I list all cells that are, for example, Animals and assign the category Animal to all of them?  Instead of having 100 separate statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use something like this to check containing of the specific text in cell, if you have a list of cases then it will be more easy to maintaining:

```
Sub AssignCategory()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range, key
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.[A2:A100]
    Dim dic As Object: Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    dic.Add "*apple*", "Fruit"
    dic.Add "*watermelon*", "Fruit"
    dic.Add "*racoon*", "Animal"
    dic.Add "*lion*", "Animal"
    dic.Add "*quartz*", "Mineral"

    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        For Each key In dic
            If LCase(cell) Like key Then
                cell.Offset(, 2).Value = dic(key)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

If you need to check that cell equals to specific text then use `select ... case`:

```
Sub AssignCategory2()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.[A2:A100]

    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        Select Case LCase(cell)
            Case "apple", "watermelon": cell.Offset(, 2).Value = "Fruit"
            Case "racoon", "lion": cell.Offset(, 2).Value = "Animal"
            Case "quartz": cell.Offset(, 2).Value = "Mineral"
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try Select...case
[microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/select-case-statement)

Answer (score 1):

A Select Case statement will allow you to stack multiple options into one result.

```
Sub AssignCategory()

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A100")
    For Each cell In rng.Cells

        Select Case lcase(cell.value2)
          case "apple", "orange", "pear", "watermelon"
            cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Fruit"
          case "lion", "raccoon"
            cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Animal"
          case "quartz"
            cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Mineral"
          case else  'no match to anything above
            cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "no category"
        end select

    Next cell

End Sub
```

BTW, the InStr is typically used to locate a sub-string inside another string. From your description, it seems you want a 1:1 direct comparison.

Comment: Thanks!  That works exactly how I wanted it to.  And thanks for the InStr tip, I did want a 1:1 comparison.

Answer (score 0):

for me, you can create 1 excel sheet that will be your datatable and then you can create a function to read the excel sheet and work like sql.

see example below. make sure on reference you have added microsoft activex data object library

```
Function getStringValue() As String

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset


strFile = Workbooks(1).FullName

strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strFile & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"


Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")


cn.Open strCon

''modify this sql statement as per your requirement

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A1:E346] where ID =1" ''Range

rs.Open strSQL, cn

getValue = rs.GetString

End Function
```